# Writing the transformation caused by the Toffoli gate

Tags: logic-gates

I read the following from a textbook: "applying the Toffoli gate twice to a set of bits has the effect (a, b, c) → (a, b, c ⊕ ab) → (a, b, c), and thus the Toffoli gate is a reversible gate, since it has an inverse – itself."

I'm confused why we write the first transformation as c ⊕ ab? I understand the modulo part, however, I don't understand what it means by "ab", is this multiplying a and b together?

Comment: ab = a and b in standard notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to multiply them, but in boolean this defines the "and" function.  This is reversible because if you repeat the exclusive or with the same value, the original left side value is restored.  This can be extended to a tricky way to swap two values without intermediate storage:

a ^= b

b ^= a

a ^= b

Now a' = a ^ b ^ a = b, and b' = b ^ a ^ b = a.